# HAML - how to create links so that they go to the right controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, haml

I have some links that I am trying to make work in HAML

```
  =link_to("My Disclosures", "") << ' |'
  =link_to("Create Disclosure", "#") << ' |'
  =link_to("My Programs", "#") << ' |'
  =link_to("Log Out", "sign_out")
```

What I am not sure how to do is link to different controller actions that I have.

Here are my routes:

```
scope :module => :mobile, :as => :mobile do
    constraints(:subdomain => /m/) do
      devise_for :users, :path => "", :path_names =>
               { :sign_in => "login", :sign_out => "logout",
                 :sign_up => "signup" },
                 :controllers => {:sessions => "mobile/sessions"}

      resources :home

      resources :disclosures # Will have new, get, look up a disclosure
    end
  end
```

So I thought my log_out path would have worked, but it isn't working it seems.

Also, I have this very simple controller:

```
class Mobile::DisclosuresController < ApplicationController

  def new
    Rails.logger.debug "-"*100
    Rails.logger.debug session.inspect
    Rails.logger.debug "-"*100

    respond_to do |format|

    end
  end

  def create

  end

  def destroy

  end
end
```

But I am not sure how to make the HAML links so that they lead to the various controller actions I need to go to on get and post. Any help with how to correctly link to the controllers would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Rails Guides on routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#paths-and-urls)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `rake routes` to get a list of all your routes, including their names.  Use those names and append "_path" to get the path to that route.

You should be able to disclosures like this:

```
=link_to "My Disclosures", disclosures_path
```

Comment: hi, I looked at the rake routes result, but for some reason I wasn't able to link with those routes and I thought there was some issue with the HAML.

Comment: what error do you get?  Does the page render?  Does it do the wrong thing when you click on the link?

Comment: when I click on the log out link it just goes to a screen which is all white.

Comment: As an example I have a route like this:         mobile_disclosures GET    /disclosures(.:format)                                                                                                     {:subdomain=>/m/, :action=>"index", :controller=>"mobile/disclosures"}

Comment: Should the HAML link to it be =link_to("My Disclosures", "mobile_disclosures")   ?

Comment: Or for a new one should it be for example m/new_mobile_disclosure ?

Comment: Use the path helpers as in `=link_to("My Disclosures", mobile_disclosures_path)`